# Drop-in replacement for ASP.NET default css

Tags: asp.net, css

Are there any resources for drop-in replacements for the default css that comes with the ASP.NET Website template? (.NET 4.0)

Comment: You mean you want to re-theme your app but still use the default master page? I don't think it's hard to write your own.

Comment: Well, yes. I just want another starting point for the gfx. I'm more of a coder than a designer myself. And for some small internal apps, a whole new theme is overkill, but tinkering too much with the css is procrastination ;). And no. It's not hard to do it myself, but a nice small site with a gallery view and some simple themes could go a long way... Kind of like studiostyl.es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, there was one for the MVC template - and the current ASP.NET web template looks remarkably similar to the MVC one, so you might be able to pick it up and use them:

- Scott Guthrie's announcement: "[ASP.NET MVC Design Gallery](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/12/19/asp-net-mvc-design-gallery-and-upcoming-view-improvements-with-the-asp-net-mvc-release-candidate.aspx)"
- Codeplex Site: "[MvcContrib Template Gallery](http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/)"

However I found that the layouts, CSS and Images from [Free CSS Templates](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/) to be really easy to integrate into an existing ASP.NET application with little additional modification.

Comment: Thanks, my bookmark pointed to the old place! This is what I was looking for too.